# Vim search and replace by decrementing back-reference?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Given the following text in Vim:

```
[2] [3] [4]
```

I want to perform a search and replace and produce the following:

```
[1] [2] [3]
```

I know how to extract out the numbers using back-reference via search and replace:

```
:%s/\[\(\d\)\]/[\1]/g
```

But now the question is how do you go about decrementing the value of \1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
:%s/\[\(\d\+\)\]/\=join(['[', submatch(1) - 1, ']'], '')/g
```

EDIT: I added a `\+` after `\d` in case you wanted to match more than single digit numbers.

See [:help sub-replace-special](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-special)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of any good documentations in using \= in search and replace?

Comment: Try :help sub-replace-expression

Answer (score 2):

When you use `\zs` and `\ze` to anchor the number inside the brackets without matching them, the substitution becomes simpler, because you don't need to concatenate in the replacement:

```
:%s/\[\zs\d\+\ze]/\=submatch(0)-1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%s:\d:\r&\r:g
```

Then

```
s/\d/\=submatch(0)-1/
```

And now you need to join the lines.